# ko binding for checkbox: change 'checked' attr from code not change the observable field

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, knockout.js, breeze

I have checkbox at html that is binding to observable-field (field of breeze entity).

```
   <input id="chk1" type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: data().isBirthday"/>
```

The binding works well from the tow sides:
When I write at code:

```
     data().isBirthday(true);
```

the checkbox become checked.

and when I write at code

```
     data().isBirthday(false);
```

the checkbox become unchecked.

And when I choose the checkbox by clicking with mouse - the observable field gets value of true. (Or when I unchecked by mouse - it gets value of false).

sometime, I need to change the checked attribute of the checkbox by code, specifically by retrive checkbox with jquery.
(I cannot do it by the observable field becouse of any reasons).

I do:

```
    var control = $('#chk1')[0];
    control.checked = false;
```

but this not change the value of the binded observable-field. It continue holding **true** value.

I tried to triiger the change event:

```
   $(control).change()
```

It didn't help.
So, what should I do?

Here is an example:

https://jsfiddle.net/kevinvanlierde/72972fwt/4/

Comment: Both @AleJuliet and your code for (un)checking the box should work (tested). There's something else preventing it to work that you haven't included here. Perhaps provide a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) with the full code.

Comment: I have added jsFiddle, however, it doesn't succeeded to load knockout library correctly. If you can do it for me.... Thanks!

Comment: I've edited your fiddle with the correct link to load KO. As you see there is no problem, and it works. In the future you should not add direct download links but get them from a CDN, like [Google's](http://ajax.googleapis.com) or [cdnjs](http://cdnjs.com).

Answer (score 0):

Can we see the html code?

Try $('#chk1').prop("checked", false);